# Continuous Time Stochastic Process

Tags: stochastic-processes

I am trying to build a stochastic model where two processes happen
randomly with different rates that depend on the status of the system.

Imagine you have a grid NxN made of 0 or 1.

The 1 elements turn into 0 with a constant rate $\lambda_1$.

The 0 elements that are adjacent to at least 1 element turn into 1 with a rate $\lambda_0$.

I would like to study this process, but as I have no background in stochastic processes, I find this quite complicated.

I have to finde the average number of 1s at time $t$.

Thanks in advance for the hints!

Comment: If you did'nt study any stochastic processes maybe you should start out with something simpler ... or you could try to simulate (program) your process on a computer and see ...

Comment: I already have computer simulations (using Gillespie algorithm), what I'd like to find in a theoretical estimate of what I see from the simulations...

Answer (score 0):

Don't have the time to solve your problem explicitly, but I think I can put you on the right track. Your problem description sounds exactly like an [Ising model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model#Pairwise_correlated_bits), which is an extremely well studied class of models.

Comment: yes it seems :) thanks a lot!